# Open csv file using Ifstream c++

Tags: android, c++, csv, ifstream

I'm trying to open csv file using ifstream but it couldn't find the right way
I git this error : No valid input file was given, please check the given filename

```
static void read_csv(const string& filename, vector<Mat>& images, vector<int>& labels, vector<string>& infolabels, char separator = ';') {
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
    if (!file) {
        string error_message = "No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.";
        CV_Error(Error::StsBadArg, error_message);
    }
...
}
```

I'm calling this function:

```
const string fn_csv = "C:\\Users\\XXX\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Application\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\face.txt";
    read_csv(fn_csv, images, labels,infolabels);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists and the path supplied is correct ?

Comment: Yes I do but the path must be `C:\Users\XXX\AndroidStudioProjects\Application\app\src\\main\res\raw\face.txt`

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check whether the file exists in the path you are supplying. Here's something you can try out

```
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream myfile ("C://somefolder//yourfile.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else 
     std::cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Also a conversion to a C string using c_str() is unnecessary. The ifstream constructor accepts std::string objects.

Comment: I'm using Android studio! Where can I find the return value of cout!

Comment: the code I've shown you can be compiled as a Windows C++ console app. What's the code you have in the else part of your logic?

Comment: std::cout is the stream attached to the standard output. On Android you'll have to use logging statements and see the output on the debug window of Android studio